# Y axis is disordered when plotting multiple data with panda dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple data from a single dataframe with a datetime index. My database look like this:

[image]

The column "Buy price" and "Sell price" has the same price as the the column "Price". The goal is to set markers on the main line, which is based on the column "Price". Here is a snippet of my graph without adding "Buy price and "Sell price" columns.

[image: Only one y]

Here is my code:

```
df=data()

xdate=df.index
yprice=df["Price"]
ybuy=df["Buy price"]
ysell=df["Sell price"]

fig,ax= plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(xdate,yprice,"-")
ax.plot_date(xdate,ybuy,"gD")
ax.plot_date(xdate,ysell,"rD")

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,10,20,30,40,50]))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the columns "Buy price" and "Sell price" get disordered on the Y-Axis and the data of "Price" get all grouped together. Is there a way to straighten the y-axis in ascending order?

[image: With multiple plot]

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are plotting strings. Instead you probably want to plot the y data as numbers (float) and the x data as dates (`datetime` or `numpy.datetime64` or `pandas.Timestamp`).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I needed to replace the "" values with: df["Buy price"].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True) and df["Sell price"].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)